# How can I change the description of an existing Gradle task?

Tags: gradle

How can I change the description of an existing Gradle task? I have tried

```
tasks.idea.doFirst {
    description = "asda"
}
```

and

```
tasks.idea.doLast {
    description = "asda"
}
```

but  neither change the decription listed when I run `gradle tasks`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the description in the *configuration phase*:

```
tasks.idea {
    description = "asda"
}
```